# Data transfer speed between AWS regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, internet, amazon-vpc, rds

Does anyone know what sort of data transfer speed we should be seeing on a VPC peering connection between 2 AWS regions (in this case us-west-2 and eu-west-2)?

We tested this a couple of weeks ago, and saw speeds in excess of 200MB per second. Today, we are seeing speeds at ~10MB per sec.

Obviously, we are using public transport networks here, so we would expect some variance based on time, but 10MB per sec seems *very* slow.

Given that AWS facilitates cross-region replication of DBs in RDS, presumably they anticipate much faster speeds that this.

Answer (score 2):

Throughput depends on the instance size and can be Moderated, Low, High or even static 10/25 Gigabit.

I would start small benchmarking network throughput between EC2 instances: 
https://aws.amazon.com/ru/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/network-throughput-benchmark-windows-ec2/

This info might be of help here as well (Enhanced Networking):
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/enhanced-networking.html

Comment: Throughput between regions has nothing to do with Instance Size. Inter region traffic is dumped on to the public internet. The bandwidth available is a factor of the route between source and destination and the degree to which AWS throttle the connection at their borders. Even the smallest EC2 instance will have more network capacity than is typically available between regions.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the AWS regions involved, you can experience different transfer speeds and latencies. Latency could be a significant part of what you are experiencing. And even different EC2 instances.  You can't expect consistent speeds, and unfortunately there are a lot of factors that will impact that speed.

Concurrency Labs did some testing on AWS regions and there was significant latency between the Western US and Western Europe. Data transfer times were in the upper middle of the testing range. Their conclusion was that the choice of regions can significantly impact an AWS implementation.

Your post doesn't mention additional testing of transfer speeds, so neither of us know what the "normal" is for your locations. I would recommend you optimize your network and data as much as possible for efficient transfer. And timing can have an impact, so try to keep your transfers to off hours; tricky since you have about an 8 hour time difference.